# Java Regular Expression <elipses>

Tags: java, regex

I am reading though some old code that seems to aim to take out a sequence of periods (......) in a table of contents.  It utilizes a java regular expression to accomplish this.  This is the code that was used.

```
input = input.replaceAll( ".*<elipses>.*", "" );
```

However I don't see mention of a regex with "<>'s" except here:

Special constructs (named-capturing and non-capturing)
`(?<name>X)`    X, as a named-capturing group

(http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)

What does the `<elipsis>` mean?

Comment: Are you sure you don't have literally `<elipses>` in your text? `.*` is greedy so I don't see how `<elipses>` would work as a match for `...`.

Comment: Is that actually the literal code copied and pasted, as opposed to something out of documentation?

Comment: The above code is what was in the old code.  I was just trying to understand what they were originally trying to do. It is not out of Java's documentation.

Comment: http://regex101.com/r/bW8tL3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That *looks* like a Java 7 named group with what appears to be incorrect syntax.

The correct syntax would be something like:

```
//                           | named group "stuff" matches 0 or more characters
//                           |           | named group "ellipses" 3 consecutive dots
//                           |           |                     | non grouped stuff
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?<stuff>.*)(?<ellipses>\\.\\.\\.).*");
String input = "blah ... blah";
Matcher m = p.matcher(input);
if (m.find()) {
    // printing back reference to named group "stuff"
    System.out.println(m.group("stuff"));
    // printing back reference to named group "ellipses"
    System.out.println(m.group("ellipses"));
}
```

**Output**

```
blah 
...
```

Otherwise your `Pattern` is attempting to actually match some markup containing `<ellipses>`, preceded by any number of characters, followed by the same.

Some API reference to Java 7 named groups [here.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#groupname)

Comment: Cool that you can do this.